# WPF: DoubleAnimation "To" property binding timings

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, binding

I'm trying to make a `Button` that opens/closes some panel using animation on the `Height` property of that panel.

Approach is to bind "To" value of the animation to viewmodel property, which is changed in the button's command.

I suppose that it should work like this:

1. `Button` is clicked
2. The viewmodel checks its "IsOpened" property
3. If it is True,  then vm sets it to False and `TargetHeight` to 0; If it is False, then vm sets it to True  and `TargetHeight` to 128
4. Animation fires and changes Height to desired value

But in reality it works this way:

1. `Button` is clicked
2. Animation fires and changes `Height` to previously set value
3. The viewmodel checks its "IsOpened" property and changes its value

Because of that, viewmodel is setting target height not for current click on the button, but for next time in future.

What should I change to make it right? 
Already tried setting `BeginTime` property to delay animation, it didn't help, unfortunately.

Code is as follows:

XAML

```
<Button Command="{Binding SwitchBottomPanel}">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BottomPanel"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                         To="{Binding TargetHeight}"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:0.3"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Viewmodel class:

```
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private double _targetHeight;
    private bool _isBottomOpened;
    private double _bottomHeightBig = 128;

    public double TargetHeight
    {
        get { return _targetHeight; }
        set
        {
            _targetHeight = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TargetHeight));
        }
    }

    public bool IsBottomOpened
    {
        get { return _isBottomOpened; }
        set
        {
            _isBottomOpened = value;

            if (value == true) TargetHeight = _bottomHeightBig;
            else TargetHeight = 0;

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsBottomOpened));
        }
    }

    public ICommand SwitchBottomPanel { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SwitchBottomPanel = new DelegateCommand(() => IsBottomOpened = !IsBottomOpened);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SwitchBottomPanel));

        IsBottomOpened = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PropertyChanged` event for the view model and start the animation programmatically in the view:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
    }

    private MainViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as MainViewModel;

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;

    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
        ViewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;

    private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        BottomPanel.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            To = ViewModel.TargetHeight,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)
        });
}
```

Just because you can implement things like animations in pure XAML, it doesn't mean that you always should. This is an example where it makes perfect sense to implement your view-logic using an expressive programming language like C# instead of using a markup language like XAML.

You might also want to consider specifying the actual height in the view, and bind to the `IsBottomOpened` property:

```
<Grid x:Name="BottomPanel" Background="Yellow" Height="0" Width="200">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBottomOpened}">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                         To="128"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

If you do this, you could also replace the `Button` element with a `ToggleButton` and bind to its `IsChecked` property rather than using an `IsBottomOpened` source property. Whether you actually need these properties in the view model depends on your requirements.

Comment: DataTrigger approach worked out perfectly, thank you!
Since I want to stick with MVVM I consider the best practice is ViewModel to know only about state of the panel, not its size characteristics. This way with DataTrigger fits it perfectly.